# Javascript object literals don't allow references to existing values?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, defined thus:

```
var obj = {
    'title': 'foo',
    'id': '123',
    'category': 'aaa',
    'meta': 'blah blah'
};
```

I'd like to subset it, however, I discovered some behavior in JS which I don't understand:

```
var foo = {obj.title: obj.id}; // doesn't work
var bar = {obj['title']: obj['id']}; // this doesn't either

var baz = {}
baz[obj.title] = obj.id // this works fine.
```

## Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @geekchic: Its a very obvious syntax error.

Comment: You can put whatever expressions you like for the value of each property, but the name of the property must be a string, number, or identifier. So `{ 'title' : anotherobject.property }` is allowed, but `{ anotherobject.property : 'value' }` is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is how it is defined in [ECMAScript 5, Section 11.1.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5):

A property name must be either:

> ```
> PropertyName :
>     IdentifierName
>     StringLiteral
>     NumericLiteral
> ```

`obj.title` is neither an [identifier name](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.6), nor a string or numerical literal. But even if you'd assign the title to another variable before, you see that the production rule does not evaluate the identifier:

> The production *PropertyName : IdentifierName* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the String value containing the same sequence of characters as the *IdentifierName*.

---

Just to elaborate on why it is not a valid identifier name: The [full stop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002e/index.htm) (`.`) belongs in [*Puncuation, other [Po]*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm) category, which is not part of the allowed characters. These are, among others:

> **UnicodeLetter**: 
>       any character in the Unicode categories "Uppercase letter (Lu)", "Lowercase letter
>       (Ll)", "Titlecase letter (Lt)", "Modifier letter (Lm)", "Other letter (Lo)", or "Letter
>       number (Nl)".
>
> **UnicodeCombiningMark**: 
>       any character in the Unicode categories "Non-spacing mark (Mn)" or "Combining
>       spacing mark (Mc)"
>
> **UnicodeDigit**: 
>       any character in the Unicode category "Decimal number (Nd)"
>
> **UnicodeConnectorPunctuation**: 
>       any character in the Unicode category "Connector punctuation (Pc)"

Comment: +1 A little off-topic, but when looking there, they state an identifier name is not a reserved word. Still, `({for: 123}).for === 123` yields `true` even though `for` is a reserved word. Do you perhaps know why?

Comment: I understand it that a *identifier* is an *identifier name* but *not a reserved word*. So, an *identifier name* is any valid character sequence. They are defined as *IdentifierName : IdentifierStart | IdentifierName IdentifierPart*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I guess my question should have been "why doesn't JS let me use things that evaluate to strings as property names."